# Garbage collector don't run when object is referenced.Which object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

As there are so many objects being created for a particular class some of which could be referenced and some can be anonymously lying in the heap and hence elgible for garbage collection . So is the presence of even one non referenced object in the heap is enough for garbage collector to run or is there any other criteria to assure the garbage collector is executed.

Thanks

Jayendra

Comment: You can always force the Garbace Collector execution, with `System.gc()`. For what concern the automated execution condition, it is not specified. So, do not base your code on it.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin you cannot *force* gc execution. You can only *ask* JVM for it.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin That is not correct. `System.gc()` does nothing. It just tells the JVM that you'd like to run a Garbage Collection right now, but the JVM does not need to follow that liking at all. It might even decide to run just 2 statements after your call. In practice you should not rely on `System.gc()` doing anything at all ever.

Comment: If the memory isn't needed at all and there's a high CPU load, maybe you don't *want* the GC running. Modern JVMs do a very good job at balancing memory overhead from garbage with CPU overhead from GC.

Comment: Garbage collection is done at the JVM's discretion. There isn't a rule saying "It will run under exactly these circumstances."

Comment: Read the basics on GC. There are more variables in play than just referenced objects. http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html

Answer (score 2):

we don't know when GC get executed, it depend on lots of things e.g. Type of GC. Also you can recommend to VM to launch GC by doing `System.gc()`. But again it is just a recommendation

Comment: finalize() method can be used to detect when object is going to be removed by gc

Comment: @FastSnail you can make an Object referenced from `finalize()` method and it won't be GCed.

Comment: finalize() is called on an object when the GC determines there are no more references to the object. It is still not guaranteed when and if GC is ever called on an object.

Comment: @jdv small correction, finalize get executed before collecting the object. But how it determined when to collect it it depends on GC

Comment: @maxormo, my statement is correct, and does not contradict "the usual purpose of finalize, however, is to perform cleanup actions before the object is irrevocably discarded". finalize() is called "by the garbage collector on an object when garbage collection determines that there are no more references to the object". However, the object is technically no longer reachable by any thread (except as a result of an action by another finalizer.)

Answer (score 1):

GC on an object is, for typical reference implementations of the JVM, completely non-deterministic. There is no way to guarantee when, or even if, the GC will be run, never mind if it will result in a particular object reference being released (and its corresponding finalizer called.) This is regardless of the state of this particular object.

As pointed out in comments, System.gc() is merely a hint or request. In a great many cases it will result in a full GC. But consider gathering a heap dump usually results in 2-3 calls to System.gc() before the dump is generated, mostly as a way to improve the chances it actually happens.

There are experimental VMs that offer various implementations of real-time guarantees where some of this is not true.